# Hallar el numero de elementos mayores a un numero en una lista en PROLOG

Tags: lista, programación-funcional, prolog, lógica

Hola y gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer está pregunta.
tengo el siguiente problema:

Dada una lista que devuelta la cantidad de números mayores a X
Ejemplo: mayor(4,[1,2,3,4,5,6],N)      Resultado.  N= 2

```
may(0,[],0):-!, fail.
may(N,[N],1).
may(N,[H|Q],X):-H>N,may(Q,N,X),X is X+1.
```

El problema es que PROLOG solo me regresa **False** mas no el valor de **X**.

Espero me puedan explicar que estoy haciendo mal, agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primer error cuando llamas a may(Q,N,X) en la regla de la tercer linea, luego estas tratando de pisar X con X is X+1. Dicha asignacion en Prolog no esta permitida ya que no se pueden modificar "Variables" con valores ya asignados.
Segundo te devuelve falso porque cuando may(N,[H|Q],X):-H>N,may(Q,N,X),X is X+1. compara 1>4 da falso y como no puede entrar en las otras reglas(ya que una es con una lista vacia y la otra si solo tiene un elemneto) tira false y el backtracking te devuelve false.
En prolog lo que se usa y para mi es muy util para entender el funcionamiento es escribir trace. en el prompt para ir viendo como se esta ejecutando el programa y con nodebug. se sale del modo trace.
Tu programa seria el siguiente:

```
mayor(_,[],0).
mayor(N,[H|Q],X):- H>N, mayor(N,Q,X1), X is X1+1.
mayor(N,[H|Q],X):- H=< N, mayor(N,Q,X).
```

El uso del guion bajo es para que no de el warning de Singleton. Su funcion es otra, pero para no enredarte solo te digo lo antes mencionado, como veras yo creo una variable X1 en la segunda linea para poder guardar la cantidad de valores que cumplieron la condicion de mayores, y luego en el de abajo llamo cuando son menores que N porque sino, cuando apenas se encuentre con un menor comenzara el backtracking y cortara la recursividad, arrojando false.
 Espero que se entienda y cualquier cosa me respondes.

Comment: En este caso no es necesario usar el   **!**   ???

Comment: @Krasnax El uso de ! no es necesario en este caso, ya que el mismo corta la busqueda de caminos posibles y como tu unica regla aqui es "mayor()" se va para false, el cual tambien era otra de las causas por la que te daba false.
El uso de !,fail. es para negar, lo cual no le encuentro mucho sentido en este programa, por eso no lo veo necesario, desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: !Muchas Gracias! Por tomarse la molestia y explicarme, ahora entiendo mejor un poco de PROLOG.